# Can Sublime Text alter CSS file properties and values to each line

Tags: sublime-text-2, css

I was wondering if you could in Sublime Text alter a `.css` file from:

> selector {
>
> property: value;
>
> property: value;
>
> }

to:

> selector { property: value: property: value; )
>
> selector { property: value: property: value; )

If there is another solution or site that would help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Check out this post for a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066068/remove-add-line-breaks-after-specific-string-using-sublime-text

Using those instructions, you can select your line break and in the Replace field, just leave it blank.